# How can i align text under image ( and all together in the middle )

Tags: css

I have 4 images and 4 texts.
What i want to do is to use this properties (i hope you understand what i want, from the code)

To align my 4 texts under 4 images ( text to be centered in middle of image)
And  all items together, I mean images + texts to be aligned in the middle of my page.

Photo with mess of my page:

[image: photo with mess of my page]

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.galerie{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="priceing_part">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="galerie">
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="tutoriale">
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
      </a>
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="tutoriale"/>
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inregistrezi pe Farmasi si cum iti gasesti link-ul tau(formularul).</span>
      </a>
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="tutoriale"/>
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa postezi reclame pe profilul tau.</span>
      </a> 
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="tutoriale">
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

this can easily be achieved by using a flex box like i have in my example

[image]

### the code i added

```
.galerie{
text-align: center;
position: relative;

width: 80vw;
margin: auto;

border: 2px solid red;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.galerie a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.galerie a img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

### full code

```css
video {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: solid 4px #cb3131;
background-color: #c9c9c9;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
.galerie{
text-align: center;
position: relative;

width: 80vw;
margin: auto;

border: 2px solid red;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.galerie a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.galerie a img {
max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
video {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border: solid 4px cb3131;
background-color: #c9c9c9;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
.galerie{
text-align: center;

}

}
```

```html
<section class="priceing_part">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="galerie">
        <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="iframe" href="resurse/tutoriale/video/grupuri.mp4">
          <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="tutoriale">
          <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
        </a>

        <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="iframe" href="resurse/tutoriale/video/formular-inscriere.mp4">
          <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="tutoriale"/>
          <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inregistrezi pe Farmasi si cum iti gasesti link-ul tau(formularul).</span>
        </a>

        <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="iframe" href="resurse/tutoriale/video/postatprofil.mp4">
          <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="tutoriale"/>
          <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa postezi reclame pe profilul tau.</span>
        </a>

        <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="iframe" href="resurse/tutoriale/video/deschideregrupuri.mp4">
          <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" class="tutoriale"/>
          <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa deschizi mai multe grupuri in acelasi timp.</span>
        </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*The borders can be removed, they are just for visualization*

Comment: In my opinion, it's `overkill++++` to use flexbox for such a simple idea. Especially for a beginners in CSS-HTML.

Comment: @EzraSiton how is using the minimal lines of code overkill? Its neither code heavy nor computer heavy. There are other solutions that are easier but require more lines such as block display and such, but why use that instead of a føex box?

Comment: I `agree` that the solution you have given is very easy/clean & short for those who know Flexbox. But flexbox (Or CSS grid) is for more advanced users (This Q is the most basic CSS q you find). I always prefer  "hello world" examples.

Answer (score 1):

I clean up your code (The solution is by **4-5 CSS** lines of code).

`<a>` tag is `inline` element by default - So Change `a` to display [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) (or inline-block)

```
a.venobox{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

`caption` is also inline element - change to display `block` - done:

```
.caption{
  display: block;
}
```

Done :)
[image]

You do **not** have to use `flexbox` for such a simple idea (Or any other complex idea).

```css
/* less is more */
a.venobox{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="priceing_part">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="galerie">
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/199/200" class="tutoriale">
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
      </a>
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" class="tutoriale"/>
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inregistrezi pe Farmasi si cum iti gasesti link-ul tau(formularul).</span>
      </a>
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/201/200" class="tutoriale"/>
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa postezi reclame pe profilul tau.</span>
      </a> 
      <a class="venobox">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/203/200" class="tutoriale">
        <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Layout**
Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) -or- [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for the wrapper of the cards (This is not the issue of your Q). Related: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/

#### Basic snippet:

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.venobox{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.caption{
  display: block;
}

.galerie{
  display: flex;
}

.venobox{
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="galerie">
  <a class="venobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" class="tutoriale">
    <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inscrii si sa postezi in diferite grupuri</span>
  </a>
  <a class="venobox">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/399/200" class="tutoriale"/>
    <span class="caption">In acest tutorial vei invata cum sa te inregistrezi pe Farmasi si cum iti gasesti link-ul tau(formularul).</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually no one of your codes is helping me, and i am really sorry but i didn't wrote question as i had.

I want something like this:

```
[image1]    [image2]     [image3]
[text1]      [text2]      [text3]
```

What i really want is:
*Image 1 centered with text 1 - image2 centered with tex2 - image3 centered with text3
*image1 + text 1 to be in left, image2 +text2 to be in middle - image3 with text3 in right (and maybe mor images + text)

*All of the images and texts, to be all together centered in middle of page.

Previously i could do that. all 3 elements were side-by-side on page, but text with image was not centered.